# GNU Readline (libreadline): Displaying output message asynchronously

Tags: c, linux, gnu, readline, libreadline

While using readline (blocking) for user input, I would like to output lines of text to the console asynchronously from another thread.  Further, I would like that the readline prompt and current partial input line be removed from the console, the output line written, then the readline prompt and the partial user line restored - so as to give the appearance that the output was written "above" the prompt.

By what combination of readline redisplay functions (or otherwise) can this be achieved?

(Redisplay function documentation: http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC35)

**problem demo**:

```
    #include <readline/readline.h>
    #include <readline/history.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

    bool run = true;

    void* log_thread(void*)
    {
            while (run)
            {
                    sleep(1);
                    // WHAT TO DO HERE?
                    write(1, "tick\n", 5);
            }
    }

    int main()
    {
            pthread_t t;
            pthread_create(&t, 0, log_thread, 0);

            while (true)
            {
                    char* p = readline("? ");
                    free(p);

                    if (!p)
                            break;
            }

            run = false;
            pthread_join(t,0);
    }
```

**build**:

```
$ g++ -pthread -lreadline test.cpp
$ ./a.out
```

**observed output**: (input "foo\nbar\n" typed slowly)

```
? tick
ftick
otick
otick

? tick
tick
bartick
tick

? tick
^C
```

**desired output**: (input "foo\nbar\n" typed slowly)

```
tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
? foo

tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
? bar

tick
? ^C
```

Comment: What did you try already? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this in the console version of my program omphalos (https://github.com/dankamongmen/omphalos). This particular code comes from https://github.com/dankamongmen/omphalos/blob/master/src/ui/tty/tty.c.

I have:

```
// Call whenever we generate output, so that the prompt is updated
static inline void
wake_input_thread(void){
    if(input_tid){
            pthread_kill(*input_tid,SIGWINCH);
            rl_redisplay(); // FIXME probably need call from readline contex
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&promptlock);
```

}

and

```
static inline void
clear_for_output(FILE *fp){
    fputc('\r',fp);
}
```

Whenever something wants to print, it takes the lock and calls clear_for_output(), moving the cursor to the beginning of the current line. It can change the prompt at this time if necessary, by calling rl_set_prompt(). When done, it calls wake_input_thread(), releasing the lock and causing a redisplay.

I'm not sure if this works in the case where you've typed more than a line of text in, and doubt it, and don't care to formally discover what's likely a new and depressing bug right this moment, so you can experiment with that yourself.

Comment: I have since determined that, provided one properly delivers the SIGWINCH (i.e., to the thread in the libreadline context), rl_redisplay() is not necessary. I've removed it from my code, and things are working as well as they were before.

Comment: `assert(fputc('\r',fp) != EOF);` looks like a bug to me. You shouldn't rely on side-effects of functions called within `assert()` for the obvious reason that when the assert is compiled out, the function call will be also...

Comment: This solution is wrong not only when there's more than a line of text, but also because it does not clear the line if the input line is longer than the printed line (a workaround is to print `\r<lot of spaces>\r`)

Comment: thanks Alastair for the correction (good eyes!) -- I've edited my response. Thanks @user202729 for reminding me to edit the response.

Answer (score 0):

The functions that should be used:

- `rl_clear_visible_line()`. Printing `\r` won't do it well, because it just moves the cursor to the start of the line without deleting the line content, plus it fails to work properly when there's more than one input line.
- `rl_on_new_line(); rl_redisplay();` (or `rl_forced_update_display();`): After printing.

It appears that it's okay to call these two functions from any thread; however it may introduce race conditions (the documentation says nothing be whether it's safe to use readline functions from multiple threads), therefore it's better to use `rl_event_hook` and `rl_getc_function` (because `rl_event_hook` is not called when a key is held) to call the function for the main thread. Also remember to handle the says when there's no running `readline` function.