# Python: readline/input() interacting with output from different threads

Tags: python, multithreading, readline

I'm writing a multithreaded program with an interactive console:

```
def console()
    import readline
    while True:
        data = input()
        do_whatever(data.split())
```

However, a library I'm using runs my callbacks from a different thread. The callback needs to print to the console. Thus I want to clear the command line, re-display the prompt, and re-show the command line.

How do I do that, short of re-implementing `readline`?

Comment: Do you need your callback to print to stdout/stderr? One quick and ugly hack is to print many 'new lines' to refresh the whole screen. or execute system command like "clear" or "cls" based on os.

Comment: I can't do whole-screen refresh because I need the scrollback buffer. Also, that doesn't tell me how to re-write the readline prompt and whatever the user is in the middle of entering.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem? An out-of-the box solution might be to use `rlwrap` around your program instead of using readline from Python.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10973370/1347646) that solves the issue for C, I arrived at the following Python code, which works well enough for my purposes:

```py
import os
import readline
import signal
import sys
import time
import threading


print_lock = threading.Lock()

def print_safely(text):
    with print_lock:
        sys.stdout.write(f'\r\x1b[K{text}\n')
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGWINCH)

def background_thread():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print_safely('x')

threading.Thread(target=background_thread, daemon=True).start()

while True:
    try:
        inp = input(f'> ')
        with print_lock:
            print(repr(inp))
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
        print('')
        break
```

`print_safely`

- uses `\r\x1b[K` (*CR* + [CSI code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) *EL*) to remove the existing Readline prompt
- prints its payload line
- sends *SIGWINCH* to the thread that runs readline (in my case, readline runs in the main thread so os.getpid() gives the right target PID); this causes readline to re-draw its full prompt.

Possible remaining issues:

- As mentioned in the other answer, if the readline prompt is longer than one line, the line-clearing will most likely fail.
- You need to acquire the print_lock whenever printing in the main thread (this is true independent of the readline issue)
- There might be some racy behaviours when the user presses a key at the exact same moment when the background thread prints.